# Why Django doesn't find my template

Tags: python, django

Can't understand why Django can't find the template.

`project/templates/blog/intro.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% ifis_admin %}
    <p>{{username}} is an admin!</p>
    {% endif %}
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

`views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

# Create your views here.
def intro(request):
    render(request, "blog/intro.html")
```

Error: `TemplateDoesNotExist at blog/intro.html`

EDIT: Also templates settings. Not sure, but it seems to be all right

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: What are you `DIRS` in `TEMPLATES` in `settings.py`?  Also if project is an app (not a full project) what is the `APP_DIR` setting.

Comment: @grochmal BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Comment: @grochmal edited with templates settings

Comment: Try to change the `'DIRS': [],` in your settings file to: `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`

Comment: You should add `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` to the `DIRS` list.  Right now django is not searching any directories that are not `<some installed app>/templates`.

Comment: Does `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings file have 'blog' it needs that if blog is an app with its own templates

Comment: @davidejones sure, somehow forgot about that 'cause in docker django app runs without adding to installed . Now having different error : The view blog.views.intro didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: @Vinand return the render? `return render(request, "blog/intro.html")`

Comment: @davidejones now it's fine, forgot to return render

Comment: nice glad that worked

Answer (score 1):

If blog is your app and project is your djangoproject :
  By the docs(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/) you need to put your template in
    project/blog/templates/blog/intro.html
Sry about my english

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `DIRS` in your `TEMPLATES` settings. If the folder is set like you mention at the top. This adds the templates directory as long as it is at the root of the project. Same level as the `manage.py`.

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```